# Angular2 issue with Json.parse(--) method

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

Please see the below issue regarding "JSON.parse(--)"

> ERROR in
>   E:/Arkin_Angular_Material_latestCode/arkin-layout/src/app/core/service/
>   http.service.ts (62,53): Argument of type 'void | any[]' is not
>   assignable to pa rameter of type 'string'.   Type 'void' is not
>   assignable to type 'string'.

actual code is

```
refreshToken.then(response => {
                         if(response != undefined){
                            const list = JSON.parse(response);
                            const userSession: UserSession = new UserSession();
                            userSession.accessToken = list.access_token;
                            userSession.tokenType = list.token_type;
                            userSession.refreshToken = list.refresh_token;
                            userSession.isLoggedin = true;
                            UserSessionManager.addUserSession(userSession);
                             console.log(response);
                             return super.get(fullUrl, this.requestOptions(options))
                             .catch(this.onCatch)
                             .do((res: Response) => {
                                 this.onSubscribeSuccess(res);
                             },(error: any) => {
```

Comment: Which line in this code is number 62?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
userSession.accessToken = list.access_token as String;
userSession.tokenType = list.token_type as String;
userSession.refreshToken = list.refresh_token as String;
```

Comment: Thanks Maxim, but the actual issue is with                                             
   const list = JSON.parse(response);                                                                                                  compile time issue is below                                                                           ERROR in E:/Arkin_Angular_Material_latestCode/arkin-layout/src/app/core/service/
http.service.ts (62,53): Argument of type 'void | any[]' is not assignable to pa
rameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Comment: Probably `refreshToken()` returns promise of type `void|any[]`, whereas only strings can be parsed